# Divi image gallery thumbnail positioning

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, image-gallery

I am currently building a gallery using Divi Gallery Module where some images are horizontal and some are vertical.

The problem is that the theme automatically selects the thumbnail which is ok for horizontal ones, but the position of the thumbnail on vertical (portrait) images is not where I would like it to be.

For example, there is a portrait of a person and the thumbnail previews his chest whereas it would be more appropriate to show a persons shoulders and head.

Is there a way to adjust the thumbnail position and if so what is the easiest method?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest inspecting the element via your browser and finding the specific class that is placed on vertical images. Knowing the class should allow you to target the vertical images using CSS. You could add the CSS to style.css or via the Additional CSS area in under Appearance < Customizer (found in most themes).

Hope that helps!